# Внимать, внять — падеж

Tags: падежи, языковые-изменения

С удивлением заметил, как звучат знакомые строки у Пушкина:

> И внял я неба содроганье,
>   И горний ангелов полет,
>   И гад морских подводный ход,
>   И дольней лозы прозябанье.

Заметил, что "внял (что?)", а не "чему". Раньше как-то не обращал внимания. И нашёл подтверждение тому, что раньше действительно говорили с *винительным* падежом.

А кто-нибудь знает или, может, хотя бы знает, как разобраться, *когда* дательный падеж сменил или начал заменять (если это долгий процесс) винительный? Ещё в XIX или уже в XX веке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Пушкина отражена грамматика того времени. "Внял" управлял точно как современный "перенял" - что и от кого (+чему).

Внять/внимать (а это видовая пара и естественным образом используют одинаковое управление) в те времена был глаголом переходным, со значением принять, усвоить "кого, что". При этом непереходное управление (внять чему) тоже могло использоваться, хотя и крайне редко и только для обозначения носителя "внимаемой" ценности. Ну примерно как "Я внял Богу его советы". Сейчас подобные конструкции воспринимаются совершенно с другим смыслом: не внял, а вменил. Видимо, это было одной из причин утраты переходности. Вторая, как я понимаю, крайняя редкость ситуации, когда источник (носитель) того, что вменяют (Бог), отличается от самого этого объекта (совета Бога). Посему не было большого смысла последовательно использовать оба управления.

> Ещё в XIX или уже в XX веке?

Думаю, годах в 60-х — 80-х XIX. Тогда вообще произошла последняя на сей день сколько-нибудь значительная грамматическая революция. Но могу ошибаться.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!